# liferay session timeout service call

Tags: session, jboss, timeout, liferay, session-timeout

I have written a logic (adding user id to a static map in hook context level) while logging in. And another logic (removing the user id from the map) while doing logout. So, its not allowing the user to do multiple login. It works fine. But, if the user not signed off instead user closed the browser. How can I handle this?

Is there any specific backend service call being triggered by Liferay / Jboss even the user is not active? If so, i could implement the service and override the method. Is there anyway similar to this?

(Using Jboss CE 7.0.1 and Liferay 6.1 CE)

Comment: You can use a `HttpSessionListener` which is called when the session times out on the server.

Comment: I have used ``CustomPreSessionExpireAction`` which extends ``SessionAction``. Its working fine.